# How to remove the entire row with string and numeric values

Tags: excel, matlab

I need to remove all rows with empty columns in excel file using matlab programming. 
I have multiple excel file and the data are in a format as follows:

```
admin  img1  1
admin  img2  1

admin  img3  1

admin  img4  1
```

I need to delete all blank rows in all these files which do not contain any data.

I found a great code snippet which fulfills my requirement but it only deletes numeric data.

Q:\ The following code deletes all rows which contain only numeric data in case of delete rows contain string data which type of modifications we have to do and one more thing in case I have many excel file?

```
e = actxserver ('Excel.Application'); %// open Activex server
ewb = e.Workbooks.Open('c:\test\test.xlsx'); %// open file (enter full path)
eur = ewb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange; %// lets simplify using active sheet
data = cell2mat(eur.Value); %// get numeric data
idx = find(any(isnan(data),2))'; %'// find rows with empty (or text) cells
for k=idx(end:-1:1)
    eur.Rows.Item(k).Delete; %// delete entire row from the last one
end
ewb.Save %// save to the same file
ewb.Close(false)
e.Quit
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to write this as a VBA macro and then just make Excel call that macro from Matlab? Also, I'm assuming you are doing many other calcs in Matlab to warrant using it at all for this task (i.e. you're doing more than just deleting empty rows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution. I'm using testxls.xlsx as an example source. It has empty cells.

First import the file: Use the import module and import data as cell array. The import module can generate code for you so you can later batch process all the files.

```
[~, ~, data] = xlsread('C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MATLAB\testxls.xlsx','Sheet1');
data(cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(x) && isnumeric(x) && isnan(x), data)) = {''};
```

Then process cell array, discard rows that have empty cells. Then save the resulting array into excel file.

```
ii = 1;
while true
    try
        if any(strcmp('', data(ii,:)))  % find rows with empty cell
            data(ii,:) = [];               % remove the row
        else
            ii = ii+1;
        end
    catch
        break  % When the process goes beyond the end, stop the loop.
    end
end
xlswrite('processed.xlsx', data)
```

Comment: thank you sir , what is mean by dest , i got confuced what is the use of this  word , also i got error around it . thanks

Comment: sorry, I modified my code and forgot to change the last statement. I changed it to make it easier to understand. data is the cell array that contains data imported from the xlsx file. Once it's processed, it's saved to another file named 'processed.xlsx'

Comment: thank you sir for your reply , its working well but its write the same output of my original file , its don't delete the rows which contain full empty cell .

Comment: oh. there was still some mistake in the code. This should work now.

Comment: thank you very very very much this is very great work sir ... its working very fine ,,, thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
1. highlighting the columns or rows
2. click the edit tab and select Go To 
3. then select special and then blank
4. Then go to home and under cells you can remove rows or columns

Comment: thanks all , but i need to do that in matlab programming i don't have much more knowledge in other programming language and also my code in matlab produced like this output , 

if any help to save the above data in an array and print them as intersection i will be very happy for that ,, thanks